# Ошибка в регекспе с русскими символами Python: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1

Tags: python, unicode

Когда использую русские буквы не работает код:

```
average = int(re.findall(u'Среднее = (\d+)', out)[0])
```

Исключение:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0:
 invalid continuation byte

Comment: Ну а `out` в какой кодировке?

Comment: Есть ли исходном коде декларация кодировки на самом верху? Соответствует ли фактическая кодировка файла этой декларации? Приведите полный (но минимальный) пример кода и полный traceback. Какая версия Питона, операционной системы, куда вывод идёт (консоль, IDE)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вероятно `SyntaxError` вызван тем что декларация кодировки файла (наверху самого файла) не соответствует фактической кодировке файла. Используйте редактор, который сохраняет файлы в utf-8.

Например, если сохранить текст в `utf8-charset.py` файл:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = u"по-русски"
```

и запустить: `python utf8-charset.py`, то ничего не произойдет (нет ошибки). Но если этот файл сохранить в другой (противоречащей декларации внутри файла) кодировке:

```
$ iconv -t 866 utf8-charset.py > wrong-866-charset.py
```

то при запуске той же команды: `python wrong-866-charset.py` печатается ошибка:

```
  File "wrong-866-charset.py", line 3
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaf in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1):

[Добавьте определение кодировки исходного кода](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) в исходном файле, **установите кодировку UTF-8**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
```

**По умолчанию исходный код интерпретируется в [ASCII кодировке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)**. ASCII кодировка не имеет русских символов.
Дополнительно можно также проверить и в случае необходимости пересохранить исходный файл в кодировке UTF-8 в любом текстовом редакторе.
Проблема должна исчезнуть.

Comment: ошибка *уже* упоминает utf-8. Поэтому ascii тут ни причём. Наиболее вероятная причина это то что фактическая кодировка файла не utf-8 (которая *уже* указана в исходном коде)

Comment: @jsf, да, вы правы. Тогда остается пересохранить исходный файл в кодировке utf-8.