# Visual Studio 2022 на python не понимает русский язык

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Даже если написать просто `print('Привет')`, то выдаёт такую ошибку **SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte** Единственное, что я понял так это то, что надо установить кодировку windows1251, но куда, как и где? И может вообще не надо ничего устанавливать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526785/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-python-syntaxerror-unicode-error-utf

Comment: Лучше пересохраните файл в кодировке utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам же и отвечу. На этом сайте https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2022 можно найти как поменять кодировку. И вот что делать если у вас нет пункта Дополнительные параметры сохранения:

Если в меню Файл пункт Дополнительные параметры сохранения отсутствует, его можно добавить.

Выберите Инструменты, Настроить,
Откройте вкладку Команды, выберите переключатель Строка меню и в соответствующем раскрывающемся списке выберите Файл. Нажмите кнопку Добавить команду.
В диалоговом окне Добавление команды в разделе Категории выберите Файл, а затем в списке Команды выберите элемент Дополнительные параметры сохранения. Нажмите кнопку OK.
С помощью кнопок Вверх и Вниз переместите команду в нужное место в меню. Чтобы закрыть диалоговое окно Настройки, нажмите кнопку Закрыть. Дополнительные сведения см. в разделе Настройка меню и панелей инструментов.
Кроме того, чтобы открыть диалоговое окно Дополнительные параметры сохранения, можно выбрать пункт меню Файл > Сохранить  как. В диалоговом окне Сохранить файл как щелкните треугольник раскрывающегося списка рядом с кнопкой Сохранить и выберите пункт Сохранить с кодировкой.

(взял с их же сайта чтобы просто было легче вам)

Answer (score 1):

Между тем все гораздо проще:
заходим в  параметры windows  -> время и язык ->  административные языковые параметры -> изменить язык системы и ставим галочку напротив Бета версия : Использовать юникод и т.д